# pass jquery $(this) as parameter to a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.element').click(function(){
  foo();
})

function foo(){
  $(this).css({//do something})
}
```

How do I pass $(this) as a parameter to the click event that points to $('.element')?

Comment: `foo(this);` `function foo(this)`

Comment: You say you want to pass it as parameter, so why not just pass it as a parameter? (with a name other than `this` of course)

Comment: You have to do `$('.element').click(function (event) { foo($(event.target)); })` event.target is the element that triggered the event ('.element') or you can use `this` that is the same on this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the DOM into the function with the `this` argument. Then just name your variable within the function.

```
$('.element').click(function(){
  foo(this);
})

function foo(elem){
  $(elem).css("background-color", "white");
}
```

Here's an example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mg26nqrL/

Comment: I have to pass foo($(this)) to make it work, why is that?

Comment: The function `foo` doesn't know what `elem` is. By passing `this` we're telling `foo` "Hey, this div I'm clicking? Label this as `elem`!"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
  foo(this);
})

function foo(el){
  $(el).css({//do something})
}
```